# After successful installation of Reanimated 2, why createDrawerNavigator is giving me error

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

Errors i'm getting after installation of reanimated 2 are mentioned below. Before installation of reanimated 2,everthing working fine for me. Please have a look and help me out

[image]

[image]

[image]

i am debugging in chrome browser.
please help me out.